# @ParameterizedTest can't be resolved in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, parameterized-unit-test

I'm new to JUnit testing and I would like to create a parameterized test in **IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.3**. So I added JUnit 5:

[image: Adding JUnit 5]

Then IntelliJ downloaded `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0`. Now, `@Test` is working, but `@ParameterizedTest` is not. It says "Cannot resolve symbol 'ParameterizedTest'". It's the same with `@ValueSource`:

[image: Cannot resolve symbol 'ParameterizedTest']

Code:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;

class SSTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(ints = {1, 2, 3})
    void testSlowSort(int arg) {

    }

    @Test
    void testSort() {

    }

}
```

PS: Also the package `org.junit.jupiter.params` is missing. Otherwise, IntelliJ would import it automatically.

I hope anyone can help me how to fix this. I am not using Maven, Gradle, etc, just Java.

Comment: You need to import it, the package is `org.junit.jupiter.params`. Intellij is able to do this for you.

Comment: @vandench This package doesn't exist for me

Comment: What happens when you press `Alt + Enter` on `@ParameterizedTest`?

Comment: @vandench 1. Create annotation `ParameterizedTest` - 2. Find JAR on web

Comment: According to [this](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api) the API should contain it. If it doesn't you'll have to manually add the latest version.

Comment: @vandench Could you tell me how to do that - manually add the latest version?

Answer (score 14):

In [article 2.1.2 of JUnit docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#dependency-metadata-junit-jupiter), it is mentioned that `junit-jupiter-params` is a separate artifact containing support for parameterized tests.

In [article 3.14](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests), it is explained that the parameterized tests support is currently an experimental feature.

Therefore you need to add the `junit-jupiter-params` artifact to your dependencies (i.e. Maven or Gradle).

Answer (score 8):

use below import statement [Intellisense should bring those imports automatically]

```
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest
```

Add following dependencies to your build.gradle.kts [for gradle builds]

```
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.6.2")
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.6.2")
```

Build project and `@ParameterizedTest` annotation should be available. If not, then restart IntelliJ and libraries should be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Please use these Junit5 dependencies for your tests (including @Parameterized ones)

```
val junitVersion = "5.1.0"
// JUnit5
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVersion")
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitVersion")
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$junitVersion")
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$junitVersion")
```